# pyspark & iceberg: `update *` not working in `merge into`?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, apache-iceberg

I run pyspark on AWS EMR studio

```
MERGE INTO iceberg_catalog.staging.tbl AS t
USING tempview AS s
ON t.number = s.number
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
```

but got

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException:
Syntax error at or near '*'
```

Any idea why? Anything missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `update` statement should be used with the `update set` syntax. This is an example of an Iceberg table used in AWS Athena, but please refer to it.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg-updating-iceberg-table-data.html#querying-iceberg-merge-into